# Ravana Brahmana or Asura?

Tags: ramayana, ravana

How could Ravana be an Asura  and Brahmin at the same time? Although he was born Brahmin (as son of Pulasthya Brahma) did he become or get declassified as Asura after his egoistic  sin ? Are there other examples of mythological personalities who had undergone such conversion?

Comment: "Are there other examples of mythological personalities who had undergone such conversion" I know of a positive conversion from a 'rAjan' to 'Bramhin risi' Bramharishi Vishwamitra, who was previously a king or rAjan and by his extensive tapas he saw(heard to be specific) famous gyatri mantra in meditation and thus he was awarded with the status and body of Bramhana by Prajapati Bramha himself, thus making him Bramharishi Vishwamitra seer of gyatri mantra. Ravana was bramhin by birth and Asura by his egoistic karma.

Comment: Ravana was not an Asura.  He was half-Brahmana, half-Rakshasa.

Comment: Ravan's origin is as half brahman-rakshas, because his dad was a brahmin and mother was of Rakshas kul. He was born of Sage Vishrava and his mother was Ketaki or Kaikeshi.

Comment: So father's genes prompted to Shiva's tapas and mother's.. to arrest Sita?